# How to post a file and return the status with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, httparty

This works for me in shell:

```
export TOKEN='eyJqdGkiOiIzZDkzNz'
curl https://apis.xxxxxxxx.com/v2-beta/media \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    --form 'configuration={"configuration" : {"executor": "v2"}}' \
    --form media="@recording.mp3" \
    | tee media-post-response.json | jq '.'
export MEDIA_ID=$( jq --raw-output '.mediaId' < media-post-response.json )
echo "Uploaded file with mediaId = ${MEDIA_ID}"
```

I want to do the same thing with HTTParty,  however, I can find no example anywhere that shows how these headers should be specified.

Here is what I have, but it throws a JSON error:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'pp'

token = "6Ijg3ZDMzODUxLTdlMmMtN"


url = "https://apis.xxxxxxxx.com/v2-beta/media"

options = {
    :headers => {"Authorization" => " Bearer #{token}", "Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data" , "Accept" => "application/json"},
    :body => {"media" => '@recording.mp3'}
    }
puts "*****  #{options}  ******\n"

j = HTTParty.post(url, options)
s = JSON.parse(j.body)
pp s
```

The error is:

```
(error) .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 784: unexpected token at 'Failed to create MuleMessage (org.mule.api.lifecycle.CreateException)' (JSON::ParserError)
```

Comment: Your curl command has `--form 'configuration={"configuration" : {"executor": "v2"}}'` but that seems to be missing from your Ruby code. Is that required, perhaps? Also, you have a mystery space before `Bearer` in your Ruby code, but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you're trying to upload a file. The `@` syntax (`@recording.mp3`) is curl-specific and isn't going to work in HTTParty. It looks like HTTParty doesn't suppose multipart uploads, but there is a gem called httpmultiparty that does the job. Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/77

Comment: Thanks, I did see httmulitparty but it appears to be some kind of unsupported (abandoned?) gem.  Even using it, I can't see how to set the headers properly.  This doesn't work:  options = {
        :headers => {"Authorization" => " Bearer #{token}"},
        :media => File.new('recording.mp3')
        }

Answer (score 1):

**First issue**

As [@Jordan Running](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan-running) mentioned, the '@' syntax is curl-specific. The HTTParty analogue is to pass a File object. This will implicitly tell HTTParty to use the `multipart/form-data` content-type.

**Second issue**

Because we explicitly asked for a JSON response in our headers, HTTParty is implicitly trying to parse the response as JSON (inside `HTTParty.post()`). But the server is responding with plain text, and so we are getting a `JSON::ParserError` before the response ever gets assigned to `j`.

Since the server isn't honoring our requests for JSON, I recommend suppressing HTTParty's implicit parsing by adding `format: :plain` to your request options. Then we can parse the response ourselves and respond to `JSON::ParserError` as appropriate.

**Solution**

Something like this should do what you want:

```
url = 'https://apis.xxxxxxxx.com/v2-beta/media'
options = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization' => " Bearer #{token}",
    'Accept'        => 'application/json'
  },
  body: {
    media: File.open('recording.mp3')
  },
  format: :plain
}
j = HTTParty.post(url, options)

s = 
  begin
    JSON.parse(j.body)
  rescue JSON::ParserError => e
    raise "POST request failed: #{j.body}"
  end

pp s
```

References:

- https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/multipart.rb
- https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/docs#parsing-json

Answer (score 0):

By using the RestClient gem we can easily handle the file uploads, but make sure that you install the rest-client gem.

And I have also attached screen shot of example request from postman.

And the code in controller as like below,

```
  res = RestClient::Request.execute(
      method: :post,
      url: "http://www.your_url.com",
      payload: params,

      headers: {
          'Content-Type' => "multipart/form-data",
          Authorization: "some_key",
          :Accept => "*/*"
      }

  )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLrnh.png)